# Alexa Skill Kit and Alexa Voice service for Android app queries

Tags: android, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

1. Is it possible to just have our Android app answer the question to only our Alexa custom skill and not have the entire default behavior of Echo? For example: I created a custom skill, say, calculate *Can I make an android app which uses Alexa Voice service API to answer the questions only related to calculate and no other questions?* (i.e. no default behavior like weather, music)
2. Why does the example on developer documentation app say "companion app"? Do I need Echo to use it? Can I not make an app which will answer questions but does not require echo?
3. Is it possible to get text and audio  both as output using Alexa API?

I appreciate any input. Any links and references are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of Alexa is it's voice recognition abilities, and the ability to choose an appropriate intent based on a voice interaction. If the skill is written with clearly defined intents Alexa will be able to respond as you wanted. It may be that "Calculate..." might be too vague an intent for Alexa to differentiate.

Also, the useful bit is the skill you build. You define how things are calculated, and what answer to give. Unless you are trying to leverage the voice recognition and AI you might be better off going with some other technology (and if you need those things, then maybe WitAI might be more useful to you: https://wit.ai/ it's a little more roll-your-own than Alexa).

Alexa Voice Services (AVS) is available in the US, but not yet the UK or Germany until 2017 (and who know's when for other markets). AVS can be added physical devices that have a speaker and microphone, so it is possible to use Alexa without using an Echo or Echo Dot.

At it's core, the input and output of Alexa apps are JSON (so text). Alexa parses the text response and speaks the appropriate part. I'm not sure that you can route this response in some other way than having it spoken. However, in between the request and response is the Lambda function (or native device function), so in addition to generating the response to Alexa, you could dump the response somewhere else at the same time that would be available outside of Alexa.

Comment: Thanks Katharine. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it possible to just have our Android app answer the question to only our Alexa custom skill and not have the entire default behavior of Echo? For example: I created a custom skill, say, calculate *Can I make an android app which uses Alexa Voice service API to answer the questions only related to calculate and no other questions?* (i.e. no default behavior like weather, music)

Yes, it's possible to override the commands. First of all, create your custom skills using Amazon Skill Kit, then use android or iOS [Alexa Application for
Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.dee.app&hl=en).
In "Settings", go to your product if echo/dot or your android/iOS application and enable your skill.

> 2. Why does the example on developer documentation app say "companion app"? Do I need Echo to use it? Can I not make an app which will answer questions but does not require echo?

The documentation context of companion app is only to use your hardware as an Alexa device. So using the Amazon login with Amazon SDK library the developer has the to authorize the user and get token from Amazon server for your hardware to communicate with the Alexa server.

Yes, you can make an android or iOS app for talking to the Alexa server. The  link below is to a well-developed library for the same.
https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid

> 3. Is it possible to get text and audio both as output using Alexa API?

No you will never get the text intepretation you will only get the response from Alexa in the form of JSON.